# Kubernetes Pod not able to contact another pod when Namespace specified

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm using Kubernetes on a centOS 7.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:23:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:13:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I did deploy a Nginx pod on a "production" namespace by using the following **prod_www_pod.yaml**:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: www
  namespace: production
  labels:
    app: www
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: myrepo:5001/nginx
```

I've deployed a second one (**prod_debug.yaml**) in order to check if everything is running properly.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: debug
  namespace: production
spec:
  containers:
  - name: debug
    image: myrepo:5001/debug:latest
    command:
    - "sleep"
    - "10000"
```

I can see both on the correct namespace,

```
[plaurent@kubmaster deployment]$ kubectl get po
No resources found in default namespace.
[plaurent@kubmaster deployment]$ kubectl get po -n production
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
debug   1/1     Running   0          94s
www     1/1     Running   0          3m57s
```

but when trying to curl www from debug, I have :

```
[plaurent@kubmaster deployment]$ kubectl exec -it -n production debug -- sh
/ # curl www
Nothing there
/ #
```

After a `kubectl delete po debug www -n production`, I tried to install the same except by removing the namespace specified on metadata.

```
[plaurent@kubmaster deployment]$ kubectl get po
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
debug   1/1     Running   0          10s
www     1/1     Running   0          18s
```

and when trying to contact www from debug, it is working well.

```
[plaurent@kubmaster deployment]$ kubectl exec -it debug -- sh
/ # curl www
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
/ #
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reach a pod through dns, unless you have configured `hostname` and `subdomain` for it, and the way to reach it is not as you are doing.

Probably you have a service called `www` in the `default` namespace that is forwarding the request to the pod, but on your `production` namespace you don't have the service.

To confirm what I'm saying, run `kubectl get svc` in your `default` and `production` namespaces.

If I'm right, expose your pod, by `kubectl expose pod ...`, or create a service through a yaml file.

Now, note that create a pod is a bad idea. It is better to create e Deployment with 1 replica.

Comment: Ty for your suggestion @suren, that was it ! `kubectl get svc` showed nothing at all and I had a **www** service in the default namespace. Service has been created properly using a yaml file and it works nicely I the right namespace. I also created a deployment yaml file with one replica.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the default namespace and not the production namespace because of how the kube-dns is configured by default. The [default ndots config of the kube-dns recognises `default.svc.cluster.local`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config). Thus when using the default namespace, the default values allow the kube-dns to locate www. But since there is no default entry for `production.svc.cluster.local`, the name resolution fails.

You'll need to configure a service to expose the www pod in the production namespace (might as well use [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)).